# How to automatically identify the appropriate space between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking into ebay.com and the way that items are displayed (scroll down on the page and see div content the items boxes have different height)

```
<div id="content" class="content">
```

I am thinking of doing something similar but the problem that I am having is that somehow I need to cater for the spaces between each item because the divs will be generated automatically.

Can I do this with css (maybe grouping some items together and keep a margin / distance from each other automatically)?

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYVxG/) here:

Comment: looks like masonry to me  http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSS **up to a certain level of quality**, by floating elements;

after that, you must use JavaScript.

But you should really check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), because I guess it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first-child` (or `:last-child`) to change the margin on the first or last element so you get neat spacing.